# get all the sub file paths in a github repository

Tags: github, github-api

I've been playing around with the github api (V3) recently.  I would like to get a list of all files and sub files in the primary repo of the current commit.

I can run

https://api.github.com/repos/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/contents/

and send many more requests to crawl the directories.  However the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) mentions that I could use the [tree api](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#get-a-tree-recursively) to get all the results.  But

https://api.github.com/repos/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/contents/?recursive=1

returns the same contents.  Can I get all the file paths in a single request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a request to this endpoint:

https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#get-a-tree-recursively

So, give this a try:

https://api.github.com/repos/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/git/trees/master?recursive=1