# What's the most efficient way to load a full github repo file tree?

Tags: github, download, xmlhttprequest, github-api, esprima

I'm working on a simple web page (no back-end).  It provides some basic stats about the js code in a repo.

Usage scenario:

1. User adds their auth token to `<input/>`
2. User adds repo root path to another `<input/>`
3. User clicks `<button/>` to load files
4. window.fetch retrieves a tree starting with the root directory. Something like: 
   `[{
   name:'root',
   children:[
   {name:'foo.js',contents:'<js code>'},
   {name:'bar.js',contents:'<js code>'},
   {
     name:'src',
     children:[
       {name:'baz.js',contents:'<js code>'},
       ...etc
     ]
   }
   ]
   }]`
5. Esprima parses the `<js code>` sections into AST objects
6. Other code derives stats from the AST objects
7. The page displays those stats

I got a basic GraphQL query going, but it only loads one tree level.  I'm hoping to avoid the logic and complexity of constructing a tree recursively over multiple requests.

Github's v3 recursive tree API would be fantastic if it loaded file contents.  Alas, it does not, and the GraphQL api does not yet have a recursive equivalent.

**What's the most efficient way for a web page to load the contents of a github repo's file tree?** Solutions using Github's APIs work, as do any other more efficient methods if they exist.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get all the sub file paths in a github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506983/get-all-the-sub-file-paths-in-a-github-repository)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  Github's v3 recursive tree API would be fantastic if it loaded file contents. Alas, it does not, and the GraphQL api does not yet have a recursive equivalent.

Comment: I ended up writing the recursive loader which solved the problem.  However, I'd remove it if a better solution presented itself, so leaving the question open.